# ksoap2 error with android studio

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-studio

I have imported a project from eclipse into android studio. The project used to work fine with  Eclipse.

I am using SOAP to communicate my android app with my server with php.
the library that i am using is **ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar**

The app crashed when the app tries to call a class from the library.

1) here i put the method of my conection and returns a jSON ARRAY.

```
import android.util.Log;
import motelalpaso.datos.Config;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class ConexionSoap {

    public static JSONArray get_json_array(String method, String[]... params){

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            SoapObject result = null;
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Config.NAMESPACE, method);
            for(int i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
                    request.addProperty(params[i][0], params[i][1]);
            }

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = newSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            envelope.dotNet = false;
            try{
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(Config.URL);transporte.call(Config.NAMESPACE + "/" + method,  envelope);Log.d("try", "Llego hasta aqui");
                    result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                    array = new JSONArray(result.getProperty(1).toString());
            }catch(Exception e){

                    Log.d("Error", e.getMessage());
            }



            return array;
    }

  }
```

2) These are the parameters that contains the necessary for the communication.

```
  public class Config {
public static final String NAMESPACE = 
  "http://www.motelalpaso.cl/webservice/android/";
    public static final String BY_LOCATION = "obtener_por_location";
  public static final String BY_NAME = "find_autos_by_namek";
public static final String URL =
"http://www.motelalpaso.cl/webservice/android/moteles.php";
  }
```

3) Finally the error what i got..
I hope you find what i am doing wrong..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
    at motelalpaso.negocio.ConexionSoap.get_json_array(ConexionSoap.java:18)
    at motelalpaso.ui.BuscarNombre$1$1.doInBackground(BuscarNombre.java:55)
    at motelalpaso.ui.BuscarNombre$1$1.doInBackground(BuscarNombre.java:40)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First put your lib into libs folder, then right click it and select "Add as library".
Open build.gradle file and add your library

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

Finally go to root folder in a terminal and run "./gralew clean", rebuild and run your android app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "" on your call:

```
transporte.call("\"" + Config.NAMESPACE + "/" + method + "\"",  envelope); //It should work fine
```

Answer (score 0):

add repository in your app gradle file...

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}
```

and then add compile dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.1'
}
```